# Matlab: Obtaining an exact decimal number from a csv file

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a CSV file where I have decimal numbers like 1.1, 1.10, 1.100. When I load the file in Matlab using importdata or even textscan, it show all these numbers same: 1.1 discarding 0's at the end. But, I have different meaning of them.

Is there anyway to recover?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: There is not different between 1.1 and 1.10. so it displays that

Comment: What is the different meaning you imply? As other point out, there is not mathematical difference. If your objective is to retain the same **formatting**, in other words how you display it, then please make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying you mean something different by 1.1 than by 1.100000? Mathematically, they are the same number (I sincerely hope you know this already).

So if your "numbers" don't have the same meaning as numbers in any of the strictly defined mathematical number systems (which MATLAB normally assumes is the case), you should import them as *strings* (`%s`) rather than numbers (`%d`, `%f`, etc.), and process them as such.